# Is VCRedist 2015 Update 1 backward compatible?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

This is probably a basic question, but I've struggled to find the answer.

I know the Visual C++ redistributables and Windows 10 CRT tried to remove DLL Hell, but is the VCRedist from Update 1 backward compatible?

**Problem**

- I've built my C++ code against 14.0.23026.
- The user already has Update 1 VCRedist installed (v14.0.23506)
- Installing the older VCRedist fails (detects a newer version).

**Worry**

Will my code function as before?

I assume entry points may have changed, parameters changed, it will probably break.

I have 2 million lines of code, I can't check them all.

**Links**

I thought compatibility might be explained here, but I can't see it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx?PageIndex=5#comments

**What am I doing to help myself?**

I'm in the process of 'anecdotal testing', but I'd appreciate any links to the official answer to develop with confidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Newer builds are backwards compatible with older builds including previous Updates, the RTM release, and the RC release.

Comment: Just to double check, before I mark as correct; if I was at all ambiguous - backward compatible without recompilation?

Comment: Yes, backwards compatible without recompilation.  If you build a DLL and test it with the Visual C++ 2015 RTM runtime binaries, it should work just as well with any update to those binaries.

Comment: Thank you, It's awesome you're looking out for these questions.